# Websocket connection error with HiveMQ 2.1.0 + Eclipse Paho javascript mqttws31.js

Tags: mqtt, paho, libwebsockets, hivemq

I am facing the below error when executing the mqttws31.js as part of a HTML file on Google Chrome.

HiveMQ was used as MQTT broker,  logs are as below

```
2014-10-28 14:46:45,043 INFO  - HiveMQ home directory: E:\hivemq-2.1.0
2014-10-28 14:46:45,065 INFO  - Starting HiveMQ Server
2014-10-28 14:46:48,249 WARN  - No license file found. Using free personal licensing with  restrictions to 25 connections.
2014-10-28 14:46:48,367 INFO  - Activating statistics callbacks with an interval of 60 seconds
2014-10-28 14:46:48,368 INFO  - Activating $SYS topics with an interval of 60 seconds
2014-10-28 14:46:48,728 INFO  - Starting on address 127.0.0.1 and port 1883
2014-10-28 14:46:48,734 INFO  - Started HiveMQ 2.1.0 in 3694ms
```

When the HTML file containing the MQTT client, the below error is encountered.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1883/mqtt' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Any help in resolving this appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have websockets enabled, to be able to use mqttws31.js with hivemq.

See settings here; http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/2.1.0/#hivemqdocs_configuration_options

`Open conf/configurations.properties with your favorite editor
Change websockets.enabled to true`

And then in your code connect to; `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/mqtt`

Here is a quick howto on hivemq' website, http://www.hivemq.com/hivemq-mqtt-websockets-support-message-log-plugin-2-min/

Comment: Thanks. Works!! Was under the impression that this is enabled by default as the reason for me using HiveMQ vs Mosquitto MQTT broker was the lack of websocket support (though 1.4 supports but need to fetch from bitbucket and generate a binary).